# New to classes and Objects in c++

Tags: c++, class, object, data-structures

I'm new to classes and Objects  in C++..I cannot understand why the linked list is not being created. It just prompts the first value then crashes. I cannot figure out where the problem is and already wasted too many hours on this. Finally decided to get some help. Thank You for your time.

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

 class Node{
 private:
     int data;
     Node* next;
     Node* previous;

 public:

     Node(int value){
        data = value;
        next = NULL;
        previous = NULL;
     }

     void setValue(int value)
     {
        data = value;
     }

     int getValue()
     {
         return data;
     }

     Node* getNext()
     {
         return next;
     }

     void setNext(Node* address)
     {
         next = address;
     }

     Node* getPrevious(){
        return previous;
     }

     void setPrevious(Node* address){
        previous = address;
     }

 };


class LinkedList{
private:
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;

public:

    LinkedList(){
        Node* head = NULL;
        Node* tail = NULL;
    }



    void createLinklist(){

        int n;
        cout << "Enter the number of nodes = ";
        cin >> n;



        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            int value;
            cout << "Enter the value at " << i <<"=";
            cin >> value;

            Node* node = new Node(value);

            if(head == NULL)
            {
                head = node;
                tail = node;
            }
            else{
                insertAtEnd(node,tail);
            }

        }

    }


    void insertAtEnd(Node* newNode,Node* lastNode)
    {
        lastNode->setNext(newNode);
        newNode->setPrevious(lastNode);
        newNode->setNext(NULL);
        tail = newNode;


    }




    void display(){

    Node* start = head;

    while(start!=NULL)
    {
        cout << "Address=" << start << endl;
        cout << "value = " << start->getValue() << endl;
        cout << "Next = " <<  start->getNext() << endl;
        start = start->getNext();

    }

    }


};


 int main(){

    LinkedList newLink;
    newLink.createLinklist();
    newLink.display();

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem

In

```
LinkedList(){
    Node* head = NULL;
    Node* tail = NULL;
}
```

`Node* head = NULL;` tells the compiler to make a new Automatic variable named `head` that is a pointer to a `Node` and set this new variable to `NULL`. This new `head` [shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) `LinkedList::head`, replacing it for the rest of the constructor. The result is `head` a variable that only exists within the body of the constructor, gets the initialization (assignment really) intended for `LinkedList::head`.

That means when you get to

```
if(head == NULL)
```

in `createLinklist`, `LinkedList::head` probably isn't `NULL` and instead points off into the wild blue yonder, so the program executes

```
insertAtEnd(node,tail);
```

and `LinkedList::tail` suffered the same fate as `LinkedList::head` and likely points somewhere you cannot safely write. The program probably crashes at this point, but it could overwrite something else important and cause the program to crash later, hiding the true location of the bug.

## Solution

```
LinkedList(){
    head = NULL;
    tail = NULL;
}
```

assigns `NULL to`head`and`tail`. A more idiomatic approach is to use the [Member Initializer List](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)

```
LinkedList(): head(NULL), tail(NULL)
{
    // does nothing.
}
```

## Sidenote

a good compiler with the warning level turned up will warn you that

```
Node* head = NULL;
```

doesn't do anything useful. Never ignore compiler warnings. A compiler warning means that while your program may be syntactically correct, it probably doesn't do what you want it to do. Warnings are your first line of defense against logic errors. Always try to understand and resolve what the compiler is telling you. It may save you hours of debugging later.

Comment: Thank you soo much sir. You are awesome!

Comment: Koodos you you as well, @ZahinZaman . I'd passed on the question until I realized this was the only bug in the program. Most of the time weeding through a Linked List question on stack overflow is a painful experience of un-or-incorrectly set pointers and incoherent logic. It's a pleasure to see someone get it right.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is your constructor:

```
class LinkedList{
private:
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;

public:

    LinkedList(){
        Node* head = NULL;
        Node* tail = NULL;
    }
```

In the constructor, you are declaring two LOCAL variables to NULL rather than the class ones. This means that the class ones point to wherever, but in all likelihood are not NULL.

Suggestions: Learn C++11 or later.

- Use class member initialization.
- Use nullptr instead of NULL
- Avoid using new and delete. Learn to use std::unique_ptr by default when you're dealing with pointers, though I understand your use case of wanting to learn to deal with pointers here and std::unique_ptrs is actually not a viable solution for linked lists nodes are things that are not being uniquely pointed to.. So forget this advice for this use case, but still when you want to new something, always ask, shouldn't I be using a std::unique_ptr instead?

Basically C++11 allows you to do this:

```
class LinkedList{
private:
    Node* head = nullptr;
    Node* tail = nullptr;
```

and you won't need a constructor in your case, though it is good practice to add:

```
LinkedList() = default;
```

if you want to use the default one.

Comment: This is a good answer, I feel it could benefit from mentioning why `if(head == NULL)` isn't passing, which is ultimately causing OP's problems

Comment: Really good answer. I passed on bringing C++ 11 into the discussion to keep the amount of new information to a minimum, but it's great to see you managed to include it without a massive infodump.

Comment: A note on the new addition: While `unique_ptr`s are inappropriate for both `next` and `prev`, there is a case to be made for `unique_pr` for `next` and a raw pointer for `prev` or a combination of `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr`. A good talk on the subject: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JfmTagWcqoE . Personally I don't like smart pointers in linked lists because they make, my opinion, the nodes too smart. I feel that managing the nodes should be the list's job. Also destroying a sufficiently large list can overflow the stack as the destruction propagates.

Comment: @user4581301 -- *Personally I don't like smart pointers in linked lists* -- I really don't like them when implementing low-level data structures.  For example, how many implementations of `std::vector` uses smart pointers as the pointer type to the internal buffer?

Answer (score -1):

change your code to

```
    LinkedList(){
         head = NULL;
         tail = NULL;
    }
```

because you have already defined `head` and `tail`.

Comment: This doesn't add anything that the already great answer hasn't mentioned.